# Convert video with broken codec information

Tags: video, conversion, video-encoding

I downloaded using `youtube-dl` from https://www.dr.dk/tv/live/dr2#!/ The saved file is `.flv`, but it does not play with `vlc/mplayer`. `avconv` cannot convert it:

```
$ avconv -i hl.flv hl.mp4
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[flv @ 0x11d1fe0] Could not find codec parameters (Video: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 2196 kb/s)
[flv @ 0x11d1fe0] Could not find codec parameters (Audio: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 0 channels, 128 kb/s)
hl.flv: could not find codec parameters
```

My guess is that the codec is simply wrong and forcing the player to use the correct codec will fix this. Is there a tool that can assume the codec is wrong, and try different codecs to see if one works?

Comment: I can not download this video using `youtube-dl`. It is showing `Unsupported URL` message. It may be due to geographical restrictions. Could you upload the video at some other place?

Comment: https://owncloud.tange.dk/public.php?service=files&t=a110ed8099a5b5fce4172e9c4810a025&download

Comment: The video size is exactly 1MB (1024000 Bytes). This is fishy. I'm guessing that `youtube-dl` didn't actually download the correct video. Maybe it has downloaded some chunk or some other flash file. This doesn't seem like a proper video file.

Comment: It is the first 1 MB. Testing with other downloaded streams that seems to be enough to show the first 0.2 seconds. I do not the copyright to post the whole file (which is around 1 GB).